# Weka Java API : statistical T-distribution

Tags: java, statistics, weka

I have been looking into Weka. I know that it can produce t-statistic values based on its GUI running a linear regression example.
So I know that it must contain the inverse t-distribution function.
I am looking for the t-distribution that takes a t-statistic and degree of freedom and returns the p-value(Probability value).

I have been looking thru the Java API of Weka, I am having trouble finding it. I can't find any statistical distributions actually.

So hope that someone that is familiar with the Weka java API to point me to some documentation on this.
Really appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup.  I don't think it's there.

Instead see these:
org.apache.commons.math3.stat.inference.TTest
org.apache.commons.math3.distribution.TDistribution